# run code when unit test assert fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert, testcase

I'm using `assertEquals()` from `unittest.TestCase`. What I want to do now is to call a function and do something there when the assertion fails, I wonder if there's a way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you shouldn't do it, but if you really want to, here is a simple example:

```
import unittest

def testFailed():
    print("test failed")

class T(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_x(self):
        try:
            self.assertTrue(False)
        except AssertionError:
            testFailed()
            raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(T)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Another, more generic possibility is to write your own `runTest` method (as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)) which will wrap all tests with `try`/`except` block. This would be even more recommended if you really need to do it, as it will keep your test code clean.

Answer (score 3):

Catch it:

```
try:
    # something
except AssertionError:
    # do something
```

Comment: I only want to execute the code when the assertion fails. I think the code under finally will be executed in both circumstances?

Comment: Yes correct. So just use try except and under except raise the exception after calling the desired function