# Executing code only when a python unittest has failed

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, python-unittest

I am working on project that has a lot of selenium tests. The tests are run using the python binding of selenium and [python unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). When tests fail then unittest displays the exception stack trace and error message. For most of the tests this is not enough information to debug the problem. Screenshot of the browser and a copy of the browser log would be very helpful.

So what I want is: if a test fails, before closing the selenium driver I want to take a screenshot and save it somewhere. For that I need a function much like [tearDown()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) but it should be called only when a test fails. I looked at the source code of unittest and specificaly the TestCase class and couldn't find anything. Can you help?

The stackoverflow community recommended [adding try...except.. blocks around each test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397456/run-code-when-unit-test-assert-fails) as a solution but there are hundreds of tests. I cannot possible edit each one. So I am looking for a general, non hacky way for doing this. Just adding [try..except..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397456/run-code-when-unit-test-assert-fails) blocks would require me going through each test and copy/pasting the try..except part or writing a decorator and decorating each test. I am also working in a team with other developers and I don't want to have long conversation why they should decorate each test they write and what would happen if they don't.

P.S. I know that I can simply take a screenshot after every test and then look at the screenshots of only the failed tests. But this is not the point.

Comment: when a unit test fails it calls a specfic given how the test has failederror which probably inherits from BaseException so you could try and except for it within the test ? although this feels like bad practice.

Comment: That looks like a good hack. But isn't there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I believe not a quick search yields a similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397456/run-code-when-unit-test-assert-fails)

Comment: Hi @FranciscoVargas, thank you for the response. I edited the question to reflect why the solution you proposed would not work for me.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov The accepted answer on the question which yours duplicates also mentions writing a custom `runTest` method and links to the documentation about how to do this.

Comment: thanks @Louis, I didn't notice that yesterday. The question is indeed a duplicate.